# How to Fill an Activity with text stored in /raw

Tags: android

I have an app for a project. my idea was to create a 3 tab app, in each tab there are several buttons representing a topic. each topic has a txt file containing some information I wish to display in an activity that is opened when clicking a particular button. so the same activity is opened, but the text filling it will depend on the button pressed.

I have everything except the ability to display the text, currently stored in /raw as a txt.

I'm looking at input readers and txt vs xml (former seems easier), and I'm still struggling.

Even if I manage to get it to display a particular txt file, I don't know how to get it to work dependant on which button is pressed.

The content holding activity has a textview which I planned to fill with text from the .txt file.

Any help would be appreciated.

I get a syntax error on that catch. spent the last 15 minutes trying to figure it out

EDIT

**activity with buttons in it,**

```
public class MartialTab extends Activity {
Button btn1, btn2;
String choice;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    TextView textview = new TextView(this);
    textview.setText("This is the martial arts tab");
    setContentView(textview);

    setContentView(R.layout.martial_tab);//takes layout from martial_tab.xml

    btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.kickboxingButton);//instantiates a button called btn1 one from the xml
    btn1.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            kickBoxingBut(v, choice);
        }//calls the method
    });//end of method

    btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.grecoroman);//instantiates a button called btn1 one from the xml
    btn2.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            grecoromanBut(v);
        }//calls the method
    });//end of method


}



  // private void kickBoxingBut() {//button1 method
    //new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("AlertNotification").setMessage(
       // "This is an Alert Dialogue Toast").setNeutralButton( "Click Me!", null).show(); 
    //creates an alert notification with the above text
  //}
    public   String kickBoxingBut(View view, String s) { 
        startActivity(new Intent(this, ContentHolder.class));
        this.choice = "kick";

        return choice;

    }

    public void grecoromanBut(View view) { 
        startActivity(new Intent(this, ContentHolder.class));
    }       
}
```

**activity that holds the info**

```
     public class ContentHolder extends Activity  {



    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Context m_Context = getApplicationContext();

    TextView textview = new TextView(this);
    textview.setText("This is the content view");
    setContentView(textview);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
    if(extras !=null) {
    String value = extras.getString("choice");
    }



    InputStream input;

    try {
        input = m_Context.getAssets().open("choice");

    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(input);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    String strLine;
    // Read File Line By Line
    while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        // Print the content on the console
        System.out.println(strLine);
        textview.setText(strLine);
    }
    // Close the input stream
    in.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
    //setContentView(R.layout.main);

   }
```

This setContentView is a problem. As above doesn't work as it expects a return type. changing it to ContentHolder doesn't work either.

Comment: as you can see, I commented out the setcontentView at the bottom, it just wouldn't work with it there. I'm totally stuck atm.

Comment: So your basically just trying to read a text document depending on the button pressed?

Comment: exactly. user clicks a button, which opens an activity with the text in it. thought it would be easy. also don't like that print statement

Comment: So you are having trouble reading the text file? is that the issue?

Comment: I'm having trouble with all of it. Outputting the text won't work wit hthe code I have, and the bit you gave me causes only one button to open the new activity so I'm clueless, at the point now where I'm ready to drop this and try something else

Comment: Nah dont do that. We will work it out. Remeber, Persistence is the price of success. So when you click the button whats the error its giving you on the ones that dont work?

Comment: YOu have to be more specific about the error your getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can open an asset txt file and read line by line like this:

```
InputStream input = context.getAssets().open(fileName);
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(input);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
String strLine;
//Read File Line By Line
while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
    // Print the content on the console
    System.out.println (strLine);
}
//Close the input stream
in.close();
} catch (Exception e){//Catch exception if any
    System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

This is a good start for you, display the lines you read in a `TextView`. Once you do this, you can move on to next step.

**EDIT**

```
package com.example.helloandroid;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class HelloAndroid extends Activity {
   /** Called when the activity is first created. */
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       // This is how you get the context
       Context m_Context = getApplicationContext();

       // This is how you show text programatically, there is also xml option, which I recommend instead.
       TextView tv = new TextView(this);
       tv.setText("Hello, Android");
       setContentView(tv);
}
```

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html

**EDIT2**

```
public class ContentHolder extends Activity {

    String fileName;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Context m_Context = getApplicationContext();

    TextView textview = new TextView(this);
    textview.setText("This is the content view");

    InputStream input;
    try {
        input = m_Context.getAssets().open(fileName);

    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(input);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    String strLine;
    // Read File Line By Line
    while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        // Print the content on the console
        System.out.println(strLine);
        textview.setText(strLine);
    }
    // Close the input stream
    in.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
```

Comment: won't that just print it to the eclipse console? Also, I've seen context used in the few samples I dug up, but I don't know what to do with it. eclipse says it can't be resolved and google isnt being friendly

Comment: In Android, your programs starting point is a class that extends `Activity`. In that class you can call `getApplicationContext`, see my edit in may answer.

Comment: In the edit to my post is the class im working on atm. The only problem right now is that catch. I've tried a lot of variations, but it keeps giving me a syntax error. Any ideas?

Comment: its becuae you are not properly closing the opened `{`. See my edit2 for the fixed version. Also you need to set some value to `String fileName;`, something like `String fileName = "myfile.txt"`;

Comment: I changed the var at the top to  String fileName = "txtfile.txt";. The last 3 lines are flagging however, eclipse wants a return type for setContentView

Comment: Check `{` & `}`, it seems they are not matching.

Comment: might help if you could explain why your setContentView is outside the onCreate method?

Comment: is it? my bad, it should be inside