# How do I pass a value from one class to another

Tags: android

How do I pass a value from one class to another.

eg

Class one

```
        public String aButton(View view) { 
        startActivity(new Intent(this, ContentHolder.class));
        this.choice = "kick_boxing.txt";

        return choice;

    }
```

This causes an activity to open. This method is called when the user clicks on the relevant button.

In this newly opened activity, I want to set the String to choice made by clicking one of several buttons. Since java doesn't do multiple extending, I can't extend the activity and this class, which I think I need in order to use inheritance.

So, what can I do to pass the choice from class A to Class B?

**EDIT**

```
            public String aButton(View view) { 
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ContentHolder.class);
        i.putExtra("choice", choice);


        startActivity(new Intent(this, ContentHolder.class));
        this.choice = "kick_boxing.txt";

        return choice;

    }
```

and in the other class, just in the onCreate (I think of these as main methods?)

```
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Context m_Context = getApplicationContext();

    TextView textview = new TextView(this);
    textview.setText("This is the content view");
    setContentView(textview);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
    if(extras !=null) {
    String value = extras.getString(key);
    }



    InputStream input;

    try {
        input = m_Context.getAssets().open(fileName);
```

key cannot be resolved.

Comment: If you search on Stackoverflow you'll find what you need : http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=passing+value+from+a+class+to+another+android

Comment: you mean pass a value from one activity to another ?

Comment: yes. in one activity is several buttons. depending on which button is pressed determines which txt.file to load in the second activity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy like this..

in your current activity, create an intent

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityB.class);
i.putExtra("choice", value_of_the_data);
```

startActivity(i);
then in the other activity, retrieve those values.

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
if(extras !=null) {
String value = extras.getString("choice");
}
```

Comment: So it would be i.putExtra("choice" choice);

Comment: If `choice` is a variable, then yes. If you want to send a pure String, then it would be `i.putExtra("choice", "your string");`. Speaks for itself really.

Comment: Right, well in his code he has this.choice = "kick" or something. So this is where i got choice from guessing it was his variable. but good point.

Comment: kick was supposed to represent a choice for selecting a kickboxing button and more so the kick_boxing txt file, but I see now I havent actually linked the txt file to the choice.

Comment: and now that I think of it, I don't know how to do that :(

Comment: forget that, for now at least. any idea why (key) cannot be resolved? See my edit

Comment: lol... Key should be "choice" when i did intent.putExtra("choice", choice); in other words its intent.putExtra(KEY, Value); so key is what you refer to the value as in the bundle.

Comment: awesome. any chance you could take a look at my file reader? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8521188/how-to-fill-an-activity-with-text-stored-in-raw